# Class not found?

Tags: php, mcrypt

I am using [MCrypt.php](http://www.kanatorn.info/2011/11/07/aes-encrypt-decrypt-between-java-php/)

#### index.php

```
include("MCrypt.php");

$crypter = new MCrypt();
```

`MCrypt.php` exists in same directory.

when I run `index.php` I get

> **Fatal error:** Class 'MCrypt' not found in
>   /home/username/project/index.php on line 5

UPDATE: I have tried including just MCrypt.php but got the same error. I tried renaming to .class.php and got the same error.

```
class MCrypt {

    private $iv = 'fedcba9876543210'; #Same as in JAVA
    private $key = '0123456789abcdef'; #Same as in JAVA

    function __construct() {

    }

    function encrypt($str) {
        $iv = $this->iv;

        $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);

        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
        $str = $this->padString($str);
        $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);

        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return base64_encode($encrypted);
    }

    function decrypt($code) {
        $code = base64_decode($code);
        $iv = $this->iv;

        $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'cbc', $iv);

        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
        $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code);

        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);

        return utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
    }

    protected function hex2bin($hexdata) {
        $bindata = '';

        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) {
            $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
        }

        return $bindata;
    }

    private function padString($source) {
        $paddingChar = ' ';
        $size = 16;
        $x = strlen($source) % $size;
        $padLength = $size - $x;

        for ($i = 0; $i < $padLength; $i++) {
            $source .= $paddingChar;
        }

        return $source;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the file called MCrypt.php or MCrypt.class.php?

Comment: is the file name exactly MCrypt.class.php ?

Comment: is that the only error you're getting? have you copy/pasted the error without modifying it? what happens if you change `include` to `require`?

Comment: When you add `echo 'test';` to the `MCrypt.class.php` file (outside the class), does it output "test" when running the code?

Comment: @davogotland yes. i tried require. require_once. same.

Comment: @Mr.Pallazzo yes I tried adding echo in the constructor, it will not output test. the same error.

Comment: @liquorvicar i've tried both combinations.

Comment: @KimJongWoo did you just post the ***entire*** contents of your php-file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your php file has to start with the php opening tag. the first line, before the class, has to be `<?php`

like this:

```
<?php
    class MCrypt {
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Including instead of `MCrypt.class.php`, the file is `MCrypt.php` if the file is called `MCrypt.php`.

Comment: I tried this earlier before MCrypt.class.php but get the same error